# Can't pass in data in store method

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, controller

I cant figure out why I am unable to pass in the **"name"** in my store method. 
**this line:-** `'name' => $id->name,` 
I did check and the variable is not null.

**Here's My Controller:-**

```
$id = DB::table('friends')
      ->where('created_by', '=', $request->created_by)
      ->where('friends_id', '=', auth()->id())
      ->first();
      dd($id->name);
  if ($id && $id->friends_id == auth()->id()) {

      Post::create([
            'title'=>$data['title'],
            'body'=>$data['body'],
            'created_by'=>$request->created_by,
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->uuid,
            'name' => $id->name,

          ]);


  } else {

     Post::create([
            'title'=>$data['title'],
            'body'=>$data['body'],
            'created_by'=>$request->created_by,
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->uuid,

          ]);
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? do you mean you're inserting value but in Table, it shows you null?

Comment: "name" is nullable in my database so i am not getting any error and "if statment" is also running perfectly

Comment: rest everything is being passed to the database except that name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, in `Post` the column name field is `fillable`.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title','body','created_by','user_id','filled_by','name'
];
```

I would recommend you to follow this way of your if condition.

```
$post = [
    'title'=>$data['title'],
    'body'=>$data['body'],
    'created_by'=>$request->created_by,
    'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
    'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->uuid
]

if ($id && $id->friends_id == auth()->id()) {
    $post['name'] = $id->name;
}

Post::create($post);
```

Comment: It was such a dumb mistake...I forgot to add it in the "protected fillable" section   *-ThankYou*

Comment: There are still 4 mins left before i can green tick your answer